# How to expose a IIS website outside the domain

Tags: vpn, hosts-file, hosting, iis-6

I have been programming remotely over VPN on my dev machine which is running Windows server 2003. My dev website is hosted on IIS 6 and can be accessed internally within the domain like `http://MyDevMachineName:8080`.

How do I expose the site externally so that I can access it from my local machine over internet like `http://MyDevWebsite.com`? At the same time the website should remain accessible internally.

I know changes are required in the website host headers and possibly in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file but I am not aware of exact steps.

Comment: You'll have to change configuration of the router that connects your machine to the Internet.

Comment: @gronostaj - so the changes are not limited to my dev box it seems. I am a developer and it's unlikely that I will have those rights. So apparently I wouldn't be able to do it without some help from our system admins.